# JSONException End of input at character 0 of

Tags: php, android, json

Somehow my issue seems to be slightly different than the ones I could look up online!

Basically I'm getting this error:

```
10-16 12:14:03.561: E/log_tag(1271): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

while trying to retrieve the following JSON result of a php script execution from an Android emulator on Eclipse: `[{"id":"3"}]`

From what I've read, my issue implies that the JSON result of my php-script (which works fine in my browser btw) is empty, but how so?

Here's the code of my MainActivity class:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    //InputStream isr = null;

    // Connect to Database + Webserver
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://10.0.2.2:8080/php/AndroidTest.php"); // My php script adress                                                                    
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "JSON");                                                       
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if(status== HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        }

        //isr = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Connecting to Database/Webserver: " + e.toString());
    }

    //Parse JSON data   
    try {
        String s = "";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("id");

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            //JSONArray jArray = jArray.getJSONArray("id");
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = s + "ID: " + json.getString("id");
        }
        finalResult = s;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing JSON Data: " + e.toString());
    }

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //MainActivity.resultView.setText("Ergebnis: " + sResult);
    MainActivity.resultView.setText(finalResult);
}
```

php-script:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","mcf");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("mcf", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM Fragensatz1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $output[]=$row;
}

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't paste your password here! And please keep in mind that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5. You should use PDO our MySQLi instead.

Comment: I can't view http://10.0.2.2:8080/php/AndroidTest.php btw.

Comment: Of course you can't, it's a localhost adress :P and I was told differently about MySQL in connection with Android. I'm running the code on a local emulator btw, thats why I'm using that adress, it's just to tell the emulator to connect to the local webserver thats running on my PC.

Comment: Oh, I didn't recognize that, because I'm used to `192.168.*` addresses. Your MySQL is not connected to Android, just PHP connects to your MySQL server.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to say, do you have a guess on what's wrong though?

Comment: If this "[{"id":"3"}]" is your JSON, id is not an array. id is a JSONObject which is the only element of a JSONArray.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it! BTW: I found out that this line here:
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
is causing the error! So my guess is that the jsonString is simply empty... but why is that? is my webserver not set-up correctly? Accessing the php through my browser works fine though!

Comment: How about using `Log.d("JSONDEBUG", jsonResponseString)` to check if it's empty? It's also recommended to avoid `?>` closing tag in php only files.

Comment: Yes, jsonString appears to be empty, but why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what the issues were:
1. I was running the Apache Webserver through XAMPP, but there was a Tomcat Server running too
2. The localhost adress didn't use the correct port, I should've used 80 instead of 8080!

Thanks for your support and ideas!